# Eigenvalues of a $20 \times 20$ symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
19&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&19&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&17&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&19&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&16&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&1&0&11&0&1&0&1&1&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&17&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&19&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&16&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&19&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&0&1&15&1&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&19&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&16&1&1&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&19&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&17&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&1&1&0&1&0&11&0&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&16&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&19&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&17&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&19
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
$$

Using a software, I found that $18$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix, with multiplicity $9$. I need to prove it mathematically. Since the matrix is real and symmetric, I thought of finding the nullity of $A-18I$ but that's tough to compute. Is there any other way to prove it ?

Comment: Can you please write down the formula/abstract description of the $(i,j)$-th entry of that matrix?

Comment: When you write, "dimension", do you mean "nullity"?

Comment: write the A-18I matrix and say v=(a1,a2,...) which is an element of the null space. then since v is a nonzero vector in the null space, (A-18I)v=0
, then you can use elementery row operations to find a form, maybe row echelon form to get a necessary and sufficient condition for v being an element of null space.

Comment: @GerryMyerson; Yes I meant that

Comment: Where did you get the matrix?????????

Comment: You question has not any interest. If you use a software that formally works as Maple, Mathematica or Sage and if the eigen-elements are rational or solvable by radicals, then you obtain the true result. If you write a paper for publication, then send to the reviewer your manuscript and  worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at $A - 18I$ you will see you have $9$ rows of only ones (each corresponding to a row of $A$ with $19$ on the diagonal).

Those rows are obviously linearly depended. $8$ of them are the copies of the first one in fact.

You can now simplify the problem:

1. write down the matrix $A - 18I$ but remove $8$ of the rows with ones only (since they are linearly dependent anyways so they won't change the dimensions!)
2. Look for columns that have the same entries. Those will not change the linear dependency at all! So you can remove them as well.
3. You should be now left with way smaller matrix.

In worst case (there are no columns to remove in step 2) you will have an $10 \times 18$ matrix.
You should try to put it in echelon form (if 18 is indeed an eigenvalue with multiplicity 8 then this should be possible without getting any zero rows.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: ‘It did mean a change of perspective, yes.’
‘But...well…surely…the privation, the terrible hazards, the daily risk of death…’
Mr Saveloy brightened up.  ‘Oh, you’ve been a teacher, have you?’

Answer (score 1):

Let $e$ be the all-one vector and $K=(6,16,11,5,9,13,17,3,7,15,19,1,2,4,8,10,12,14,18,20)$. Then
$$
A(K,K) = 18\,I + ee^T - ((D+F)\oplus 0_{9\times9}),
$$
where $D=\operatorname{diag}(8,8,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2)$ and
$$
F=\pmatrix{
0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0}.
$$
Note that $(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)^\top\in\ker(D+F)$. Therefore,

- the nullity of $D+F$ is at least $1$,
- the nullity of $(D+F)\oplus 0_{9\times9}$ is at least $10$,
- the nullity of $ee^T - ((D+F)\oplus 0_{9\times9})$ is at least $9$, and
- $A(K,K)=18\,I + ee^T - ((D+F)\oplus 0_{9\times9})$ has an eigenvalue $18$ of multiplicity $\ge9$.

Now the conclusion follows because $A$ and $A(K,K)$ have the same spectrum.

Comment: Op will you please explain what is meant by $A\oplus B$ for two matrices A and B

Comment: @Student It's the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum) of two matrices.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.But does not it only say that multiplicity is $\ge 9$ ?We need $=9$

Comment: will u please explain why nullity of $ee^T-((D+F)\oplus 0)$ is at least $9$

Comment: @Student Let $X=ee^T$ and $Y=(D+F)\oplus0$. Then $nullity(X-Y)=20-rank(X-Y)\ge 20-(rank(X)+rank(Y))=nullity(Y)-rank(X)\ge10-1=9$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org):

```
from sympy import *

A = Matrix([[19,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1, 19,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1, 17,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1, 19,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1, 16,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  0,  1,  0, 11,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0, 17,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 19,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1, 16,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 19,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1, 15,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 19,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1, 16,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 19,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 17,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0, 11,  0,  1,  0,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0, 16,  1,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 19,  1,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1, 17,  1],
            [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 19]])

s = Symbol('s')
p = (s * eye(20) - A).det()
```

The **characteristic polynomial** is

```
>>> print p
s**20 - 340*s**19 + 54682*s**18 - 5532760*s**17 + 395069941*s**16 - 21166131356*s**15 + 882953073528*s**14 - 29370793354368*s**13 + 791321447285872*s**12 - 17440025771736000*s**11 + 316151576030552832*s**10 - 4722592405018189824*s**9 + 58030753657512358656*s**8 - 583406463683957216256*s**7 + 4751863719311098607616*s**6 - 30874863028022989553664*s**5 + 156275998101853212119040*s**4 - 593868884118152929689600*s**3 + 1593920286142768447488000*s**2 - 2693994644579903078400000*s + 2156402247949143244800000
```

**Factoring** the characteristic polynomial, we obtain

```
>>> p.factor()
(s - 18)**9*(s - 16)**3*(s - 15)**3*(s - 10)*(s**4 - 75*s**3 + 1924*s**2 - 20588*s + 78640)
```

Printing in $\LaTeX$, we have

$$p (s) = \left(s - 18\right)^{9} \left(s - 16\right)^{3} \left(s - 15\right)^{3} \left(s - 10\right) \left(s^{4} - 75 s^{3} + 1924 s^{2} - 20588 s + 78640\right)$$

Note that eigenvalue $18$ has **multiplicity** $9$. Alternatively,

```
>>> (A - 18 * eye(20)).rank()
11
```

and, thus, the nullity of matrix $\mathrm A - 18 \,\mathrm I_{20}$ is equal to $20-11 = 9$.

---

#### Addendum

We can also find the roots of the quartic $s^{4} - 75 s^{3} + 1924 s^{2} - 20588 s + 78640$, as follows

```
>>> roots = solve(s**4 - 75*s**3 + 1924*s**2 - 20588*s + 78640, s)
>>> for r in roots:
        simplify(r)

    75/4 - 11**(5/6)*sqrt(4449*11**(1/3) + 78936/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 24*11**(2/3)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3))/132 - 11**(11/12)*sqrt(8898*11**(1/6) - 24*sqrt(11)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) - 168822*11**(1/3)*sqrt(3)/sqrt(1483*11**(1/3) + 26312/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 8*11**(2/3)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3)) - 7176*11**(5/6)/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3))/132
    75/4 - 11**(5/6)*sqrt(4449*11**(1/3) + 78936/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 24*11**(2/3)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3))/132 + 11**(11/12)*sqrt(8898*11**(1/6) - 24*sqrt(11)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) - 168822*11**(1/3)*sqrt(3)/sqrt(1483*11**(1/3) + 26312/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 8*11**(2/3)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3)) - 7176*11**(5/6)/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3))/132
    75/4 - 11**(11/12)*sqrt(8898*11**(1/6) - 24*sqrt(11)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 168822*11**(1/3)*sqrt(3)/sqrt(1483*11**(1/3) + 26312/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 8*11**(2/3)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3)) - 7176*11**(5/6)/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3))/132 + 11**(5/6)*sqrt(4449*11**(1/3) + 78936/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 24*11**(2/3)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3))/132
    75/4 + 11**(11/12)*sqrt(8898*11**(1/6) - 24*sqrt(11)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 168822*11**(1/3)*sqrt(3)/sqrt(1483*11**(1/3) + 26312/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 8*11**(2/3)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3)) - 7176*11**(5/6)/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3))/132 + 11**(5/6)*sqrt(4449*11**(1/3) + 78936/(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3) + 24*11**(2/3)*(4441 + 12*sqrt(1904982)*I)**(1/3))/132
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong.I cross checked with my software.It did give $9$ .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here are a basis of 18 eigenvectors, written as 9 rows, which is alright as the matrix is symmetric

```
[-1 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0]

[-1 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0]

[-1 0 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0]

[-1 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0]

[-1 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0]

[-1 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0 0]

[-1 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0]

[-5 0 1 0 1 -1 1 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 1 -1 1 0 1 0]

[-1 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1]
```

for verisimilitude, here is what happens when we multiply this 9 by 20 matrix by the symmetric 20 by 20:

```
[-18 18  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0]

[-18  0  0 18  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0]

[-18  0  0  0  0   0  0 18  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0]

[-18  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0 18   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0]

[-18  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0 18  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0]

[-18  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0 18  0   0  0  0  0  0]

[-18  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0 18  0  0]

[-90  0 18  0 18 -18 18  0 18  0 -18  0 18  0 18 -18 18  0 18  0]

[-18  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0 18]
```

here is the 9 by 9 Gram matrix for this basis

```
[2 1 1 1 1 1 1  5 1]

[1 2 1 1 1 1 1  5 1]

[1 1 2 1 1 1 1  5 1]

[1 1 1 2 1 1 1  5 1]

[1 1 1 1 2 1 1  5 1]

[1 1 1 1 1 2 1  5 1]

[1 1 1 1 1 1 2  5 1]

[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 36 5]

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5 2]
```

characteristic polynomial of this Gram matrix is $(x-1)^7 (x^2 - 45 x + 124)$ so it is positive definite and the nine rows really are linearly independent. As it is relevant: the roots of $x^2 - 45 x + 124$ are positive  and  approximately $2.9487852 \; , \; \; \; 42.0512148 \; \; .$

====================================================================

the three 16

```
[0 0 -1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

[0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]

[0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
```

here is the Gram matrix of inner products for these three

```
[2 1 1]

[1 2 1]

[1 1 2]
```

this characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^2 (x-4)$

========================================================

for 15:

```
[0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

gram, same as 16

```
[2 1 1]

[1 2 1]

[1 1 2]
```

======================================================

for 10, just one row

```
[0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
```

============================================